# How do I post a user uploaded file with python requests?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I made a ModelForm to allow a user to upload an image. I then need to POST the whole form to a back-end app as a multipart-encoded file; however, I'm failing to include the file when I post it (all the fields in payload come through, though). Using python requests, I set the files dictionary to a test image on my computer. This, from my views.py, works.

```
import requests
from flask import redirect


url = 'https://...'
payload = {'first_name': first_name, ...}
files = {'screenshot': (screenshot.name, open('/Users/Ed/Documents/boots.jpg', 'rb'))}
req = requests.Request('POST', url, data=payload, files=files)
r = req.prepare()
s = requests.Session()
s.send(r)
return redirect('forms.views.thanks')
```

I get the feeling that something is wrong with that files dictionary. I'm not strong with Python or Django, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

From what I read however, as long as the user-uploaded file is <2.5MB, I should be able to refer to upload from memory, and not have to go get it from its upload location (a series of folders nested by year, month, date).

Again, after looking up solutions, I thought that screenshot.name would get the file's filename, and 'screenshot' would refer to the file itself. But that's not working. The following line actually tricked that backend app into believing there is a file there, but on testing, it's an empty jpg.

```
files = {'screenshot': (screenshot.name, screenshot, 'rb')}
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have to first make a GET request to the form URL and grab the CSRF token which you will need to use to make the POST request with the image file.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but then wouldn't the test image I mention in the first example not post, either?